# MCMC samplers in R for inference with a complex likelihood function

Tags: r, bayesian, inference, monte-carlo, markov-process

I would like to perform Bayesian inference for the calibration parameters of a complex computer model. In other words, I have a computer code (think of it as a FEM solver, or a CFD solver, etc.) whose outputs depend on some calibration parameters, and I want to use Bayesian inference to calibrate them. I would like to do this work in R, and I would like to use something more advanced than a simple random walk Metropolis algorithm, because each evaluation of the likelihood function requires $n$ runs of the computer code (where $n$ is the size of my data set), so the less times I have to evaluate it, the better. My model has 4 output variables (so it's a multivariate Bayesian inference problem), 10 input variables and 7-9 calibration parameters ( I'm still thinking about the fine details of the parametrization). The input-output map is nonlinear.

I'm pretty new to the R MCMC enviroment. For cases where the likelihood function is a generic one (e.g., my case), `MCMCpack`, which is in the core distribution, offers only a random walk Metropolis algorithm. I tried it, but it's definitely not efficient enough for my case. Of the MCMC samplers available in R, which one should I use for this problem and why?

EDIT if no solution for a multivariate (meaning multi-output) problem is available, I could accept a single output solution, and later on ask a new question on how to extend the approach to a multi-output problem.

Comment: I really like the `BayesianTools` package which implements a range of search algorithms. Another one I have used is `rstan`, quite a different approach but very efficient.